# Почему не срабатывает redirect?

Tags: python, django

Вывожу форму на странице. при успешной отправке формы хочу, чтобы произошел редирект на страницу редактирования этой формы. Форма валидируется, однако в функцию редиректа не попадает pk, хотя он корректно вычисляется. Почему так происходит?

```
class EntityPageView(BaseTemplateView, CreateView):
    template_name = 'entities/entity.html'
    form_class = forms.EntityForm
    success_message = 'Ваш запрос благополучно отправлен'

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)

        return self.render_to_response(
            self.get_context_data(
                form=form
            )
        )

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = None
        form_class = self.get_form_class()
        form = self.get_form(form_class)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save()
            pk = post.pk
            return redirect('/entity/edit/', pk=pk)
        else:
            return form_validation_error_response(form.errors)

urls.py:
........
urlpatterns = (
    re_path(r'^entity/$', views.EntityPageView.as_view(), name='entity'),
    re_path(r'^entity/edit/(?P<pk>[-\w]{1,150})/$', views.entity_edit, name='entity_edit'),
)
.....
```

Comment: В первом параметре в функции `redirect` должно быть указано или имя роута из `urls.py`, или готовая ссылка. Если вы указали готовую ссылку, то все остальные параметры будут проигнорированы. А лучше укажите имя роута из urls.py, тогда и pk будет использован, и хардкода станет меньше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

спасибо @andreymal.

правильный редирект выглядит вот так:

```
.......
return redirect('entities:entity_edit', pk=post.pk)
.......
```